# PHP slice multidimensional array after specific word without damaging the original structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a multidimensional array, which has an unknown number of strings, arrays and multidimensional arrays in it.

Now I want to cut it after a specific word. The specific word is either in one of the strings or inside one of the arrays. The structure of the original array should be kept. How can I achieve this?

Comment: where is your multidimensional array?

Comment: You probably want to provide some examples otherwise it's unlikely people will be able to provide you with a solution

Comment: Maybe [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). Hard to tell without more details...

Comment: This is an example of the array https://pastebin.com/8Q3MPjvF , I have not posted it, because it is so huge.

Comment: The problem with array_walk_recursive is, that I would loose the original structure, because it only returns the key and value of the active element. Anyway, here is the top of my array in a readable format. https://pastebin.com/5dBNNUXm